# Validation erorr raise for the form that validates its value from another model

Tags: mysql, django, validation

I am trying to raise validation error for the entry field in the forms.py

My `models.py`

```
class StudBackground(models.Model):
    stud_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Student(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

My `forms.py`

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=150, label='',widget= forms.TextInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['name',]
```

where i tried to apply clean method :

```
def clean_student(self,*args,**kwargs):
    name=self.cleaned_data.get("name")
    if not studBackground.stud_name in name:
        raise forms.ValidationError ( "It is a not valid student")
    else: return name
```

I tried to incorporate `stud_name` from the `StudBackground` model to the form but it does not work it raises following error when i try to type student name that is not in DB:

`Profiles matching query does not exist`

however it supposed to return near the name field `"It is a not valid student"`

How to make it work? What is the wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
def clean_student(self):
    name=self.cleaned_data.get("name")
    if not StudBackground.objects.filter(stud_name=name).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("It is a not valid student")
    return name
```

I am using [**`filter(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) function from queryset to check if a name exists in `StudBackground`. I am also running [**`exists()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) to check if entry exists in DB.

### Update

I think your indentations are not correct for the view. But, you can try like this:

```
def home(request):
    form = StudentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            name = instance.name
            class_background=StudBackground.objects.get(stud_name=name)
            context={'back':class_background}
            return render(request, 'class10/background.html', context)
    # Now let us handle if request type is GET or the form is not validated for some reason
    # Sending the form instance to template where student form is rendered. If form is not validated, then form.errors should render the errors.
    # How to show form error: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages  
    return render(request, 'your_student_form_template.html', context={'form':form})
```

Comment: i got the following error: views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: You need to share your view for this.

Comment: Please have a look at my question i have added views.py

Comment: @Günel, One question per post. He is answered your question correctly but you still not approved this post. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @ruddra should i import to view.py some libraries if it says views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object ? as i ahven't imported HttpResponse or anything.

Comment: please add the full error stacktrace in your question

Comment: this is the error: The view research.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.